# How to plot integrals in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, integral

I'm trying to plot the following integral:

[image: integral]

I only know how to get the answer but I can't figure out how to plot it.

Comment: The result of your integral is a constant. Thus you do not need to plot it. Maybe you are talking about the integrand? Precise what do you need.

Comment: I need to check my numerical answer by graphing it

Comment: Do you need to plot a constant? You should precise your question.

Comment: It would help others to help you if you included the code you have already tried (for example to get the answer) here; and then explain exactly what you would like to see in your plot. As Alexander has pointed out the result of that definite integral is just a number, so it's not clear what you want to plot.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is the function cumptrapz. Trapz is just a number and cumtrapz is cumulative and therefore you will get a straight line to the highest value of the integral if you plot it.